# Why the first option is now available in the select tag with php?

Tags: php, html, css

I was programming in a php page while one error occurs in the  in my php code and I can't find the solution for it.

This is my code:

```php
<select class="filter" name="autore">
    <option value="0" hidden>Autore</option>
    <?php 
        $sql = "SELECT autore FROM tautori";
        $autore = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die($sql."<br>".mysqli_error($conn));
        $listAutori = mysqli_fetch_array($autore);

        while($listAutori = mysqli_fetch_array($autore)){   
            echo "<option name='autore' value='".$listAutori['autore']."'>".$listAutori['autore']."</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
<select class="filter" name="nazionalita">
    <option value="0" hidden>Nazionalità</option>
    <?php 
        $sql = "SELECT nazionalita FROM tnazionalita";
        $nazionalita = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die($sql."<br>".mysqli_error($conn));
        $listNazioni = mysqli_fetch_array($nazionalita);

        while($listNazioni = mysqli_fetch_array($nazionalita)){   
            echo "<option name='autore' value='".$listNazioni['nazionalita']."'>".$listNazioni['nazionalita']."</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
<select class="filter" name="titolo">
    <option value="0">Titolo</option>
</select>
```

and the Css:

```
.filter{
        float: left;
        font-size: 120%;
        width: 33.2%;
        text-align: center;
        background: rgb(172, 159, 207);
        cursor:pointer;
        transition: 0.5s;
        border-top: solid 2px rgb(121, 108, 158);
        border-bottom: solid 2px rgb(121, 108, 158);
        border-right: solid 2px rgb(121, 108, 158);
    }
    .filter:hover{
        transition: 0.7s;
        background: rgb(64, 51, 95);
        color: aliceblue;
    }
    select {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        text-indent: 1px;
        text-overflow: '';
      }
```

And my question still is: Why in the first select and in the second select doesn't show the first option starting to the sql field, and in the third select it shows?

The situation at the moment:

- Autore --> field2, field3, ...
- Nazionalità --> field2, field3, ...
- Titolo --> titolo

I wanted it like this:

- Autore --> **field1**, field2, field3, ...
  ...

Answer (score 1):

In the current code:

```
    // fetches first row, does nothing with it
    $listAutori = mysqli_fetch_array($autore);

    // fetches second row and operates on it, then third row, etc.
    while($listAutori = mysqli_fetch_array($autore)){   
        echo "<option name='autore' value='".$listAutori['autore']."'>".$listAutori['autore']."</option>";
    }
```

One row is being fetched first, before the loop fetches *another* row and operates on it.

So, with the line `$listAutori = mysqli_fetch_array($autore);` one row from the database is being read, but not used, and the loop then fetches the second one immediately.

The fix: remove the line of code before the loop:

```
    while($listAutori = mysqli_fetch_array($autore)){   
        echo "<option name='autore' value='".$listAutori['autore']."'>".$listAutori['autore']."</option>";
    }
```